# Javascript token, category search field like mail

Tags: javascript

A little while ago I came across a Javascript search box that had token input like that in Lions Finder or Mail, where the tokens have a category element that is auto completed as well as the query element. I have spent much of the day so far trying to find it, but I seem to have lost my bookmark and can't find it on Google. Has anyone else used this or know who created it?

Hope you can help.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/ hope it works as well as I hoped

Comment: I've got the same question! Visual search is great, but won't work for me. It can't handle labels/values for neither facets nor facet-values (i.e. showing one thing to the user and searching for something else). E.g. label: "userName", value: "userId" or facadeLabel: "Användare", facadeValue: "user". So if you find something else, please let me know!